# Tkinter MVC Frame Switching

Tags: python, class, tkinter, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC Program to learn about classes in python using tkinter however I am stuck on an error I keep getting that makes zero sense and is driving me crazy. I keep getting the error AttributeError: type object 'ColumnView' has no attribute 'back_button' even though it is obviously an attribute of the ColumnView class. A over view of my code is here separated into 2 folders Controllers & Views, I have not implemented any models yet as I want to get the GUI running:

Controllers Folder:

columnscontroller.py:

```
from views.main import View
from views.tablesview import TablesView


class ColController:
    def __init__(self, col_view_instance, view):
        self.view = view
        self.col_view_instance = col_view_instance
        self._bind()

    def _bind(self):
        if self.col_view_instance:
            self.col_view_instance.back_button.config(command=self.switch_to_tables_view)

    def switch_to_tables_view(self):
        self.view.switch(TablesView)
```

main.py:

```
from views.main import View
from .tablescontroller import TablesController
from .columnscontroller import ColController
from views.columnsview import ColumnView
from views.tablesview import TablesView

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view
        self.tables_view_controller = TablesController(self.view._current_frame, self.view)
        self.col_controller = ColController(self.view.column_view, self.view)

    def start(self):
        self.view.start_mainloop()
```

tablescontrollers.py:

```
from views.main import View
from views.columnsview import ColumnView

class TablesController:
    def __init__(self, tables_view_instance, view):
        self.view = view
        self.tables_view_instance = tables_view_instance
        self._bind()

    def _bind(self):
        if self.tables_view_instance:
            self.tables_view_instance.submit_button.config(command=self.submit)

    def submit(self):
        self.view.switch(ColumnView)
```

Views Folder:

columnsview.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import LabelFrame, Button, Checkbutton
class ColumnView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.column_info_frame = LabelFrame(self, text="Table Columns")
        self.column_info_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W")
        self.column_info_btns = LabelFrame(self, text="Column Selection Buttons")
        self.column_info_btns.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
        self.query_button = Button(self.column_info_btns, text="Query")
        self.back_button = Button(self.column_info_btns, text="Back to Table Selection")
        self.back_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.query_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

main.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from .root import Root
from .tablesview import TablesView
from .columnsview import ColumnView
class View:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Root()
        self._current_frame = None
        self.table_view = TablesView
        self.column_view = ColumnView
        self.switch(TablesView)

    def switch(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self.root)
        if self._current_frame is not None:
            self._current_frame.destroy()
        self._current_frame = new_frame
        self._current_frame.pack()

    def start_mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
```

root.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        start_width = 500
        min_width = 400
        start_height = 300
        min_height = 250

        self.geometry(f"{start_width}x{start_height}")
        self.minsize(width=min_width, height=min_height)
        self.title("TKinter MVC Multi-frame GUI")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

tablesview.py:

```
class TablesView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.header = Label(self, text="RASPUTIN")
        self.header.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")

        self.table_info_frame = LabelFrame(self, text="Table Names")
        self.table_info_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")

        self.button_frame = LabelFrame(self, text="Buttons")
        self.button_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
        self.submit_button = Button(self.button_frame, text="Submit Table Selection")
        self.submit_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
```

Entry Script:

main.py

```
from views.main import View
from controllers.main import Controller

if __name__ == "__main__":
    view = View()
    controller = Controller(view)
    controller.start()
```

Without this line in the Controller class

self.col_controller = ColController(self.view.column_view, self.view)

the program runs and I can switch from the table view to the column view when i click on the submit button in the tablesview but not vice versa because the controller for the column view has not been instantiated. When I add the line above I get the error I mentioned at the beginning
I have tried changing the first argument to

self.col_controller = ColController(self.view._current_frame, self.view)

because since it worked with the TablesController i thought it would work with this as well however
this results in AttributeError: 'TablesView' object has no attribute 'back_button'

I have tried ChatGPT to try and help debug but it just keeps going in circles and getting the same errors

I would really like to know what I am doing wrong and how I would be able to fix it so I can use this information in future projects as I am completely at a loss of what to do.

TIA for the help!

Comment: You've posted what seems like far too much code. Please try to reduce the code down to a single code block. See [mcve] for more help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- create the instances of `TablesView` and `ColumnView` inside `View.__init__()` and save those instances in a dictionary
- don't destroy current frame when switching frame, just call `.pack_forget()` to hide the current frame

Updated `View` class:

```py
class View:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Root()
        self._current_frame = None
        # create instances of views
        self.table_view = TablesView()
        self.column_view = ColumnView()
        # save those views in a dictionary
        self._frames = {
            TablesView: self.table_view,
            ColumnView: self.column_view
        }
        self.switch(TablesView)

    def switch(self, frame_class):
        if self._current_frame:
            # hide current frame
            self._current_frame.pack_forget()
        # show target frame
        self._current_frame = self._frames[frame_class]
        self._current_frame.pack()

    def start_mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am curious though, since you are not destroying the current frame is it loading all the views at once or only showing when it is called. My whole idea with destroying the frame is so there aren't so many views loaded all at once when this gets bigger.

Comment: @cmill Since you need to access an instance variable of a view, then the view should be created beforehand.